# Wolfram Mathematica: How can I copy list without only one element?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

E.g. I have `list A = {a,b,c,d}`

How can I get `list B = A` without `{b}` element in one command?

Answer (score 2):

```
B = Delete[A, 3]
```

or

```
B = DeleteCases[A, c]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {a, b, c, d};
B = Cases[A, Except[b]]
```